# Is there a high-level gestures library for iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, gesture

The iPhone platform has a number of common gesture idioms.  For example, there are taps, pinches, and swipes, each with varying number of fingers.  But when you're developing an app, it's up to you to implement these things based on low-level information about the number and locations of touches.  It seems like this is a prime candidate for a library.  You would register a delegate, set some parameters like multi-tap interval and swipe threshold, and get calls like swipeStarted/Ended, pinchStarted/Ended, multiTap, etc.  Does such a library exist?

Comment: I have enough to do without having to learn yet another stupid code repository. Github is crap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've set up just such a project.  It's not a library, but it is full of sample code for pinch/stretch, tap and hold, etc.

Blog:

http://6tringle.com/blog/2009/TouchSampleCode.html

Github:

http://github.com/kailoa/6tringle-touchsamplecode/tree/master

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, but perhaps just as good.  Thanks!

Comment: Good example, but not a library. I forked the project and attempted to create a library. http://github.com/bentford/GestureDetect

Answer (score 2):

Here is one for detecting the circle gesture, with the source code provided. Might be useful for adapting it to detect other geatures.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/04/detecting-circle-gesture.html

Answer (score 2):

`UIGestureRecognizer`.  Don’t roll your own.

Comment: I'd say this is the correct answer if you don't have to support iOS 3.1.x, but for now quite a few of us do.

Answer (score 0):

I forked Kailoa's very nice example and attempted to create a library.

http://github.com/bentford/GestureDetect

I intend to add a combination "pinch-zoom and drag" gesture like the one in the maps app.  Once I get it working, I'll post on github.