# jQuery RSS parsing issue with Delicious feed

Tags: jquery, parsing, rss, delicious-api

I'm trying to parse my delicious links feed to generate custom html. I was not able to parse the item.link and item.creator (index 3,4 of the following rss).

Delicious/myusername
    http://www.delicious.com/myusername
    bookmarks posted by myusername

```
<item>
  <title>Full-function Core Data example app « Peter McIntyre</title>
  <pubDate>Mon, 11 Nov 2005 04:02:00 -0730</pubDate>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.delicious.com/url/8b20ab1d1fa021f744acb67f69e22a36#myusername</guid>
  <link>http://petermcintyre.wordpress.com/2010/02/24/full-function-core-data-example-app/</link>
  <dc:creator><![CDATA[myusername]]></dc:creator>
  <comments>http://www.delicious.com/url/8b20ab1d1fa021f744acb67f69e22a36</comments>
  <wfw:commentRss>http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/url/8b20ab1d1fa021f744acb67f69e22a36</wfw:commentRss>
  <source url="http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/myusername">myusername's bookmarks</source>
  <category domain="http://www.delicious.com/myusername/">iphone,</category>
  <category domain="http://www.delicious.com/myusername/">coredata,</category>
</item>
<item>
  <title>Is there a high-level gestures library for iPhone development? - Stack Overflow</title>
  <pubDate>Fri, 24 Sep 2008 09:19:16 +0730</pubDate>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.delicious.com/url/5082a6b90d2dfecbf9673c3f61e45abc#myusername</guid>
  <link>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907512/is-there-a-high-level-gestures-library-for-iphone-development</link>
  <dc:creator><![CDATA[myusername]]></dc:creator>
  <comments>http://www.delicious.com/url/5082a6b90d2dfecbf9673c3f61e45abc</comments>
  <wfw:commentRss>http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/url/5082a6b90d2dfecbf9673c3f61e45abc</wfw:commentRss>
  <source url="http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/myusername">myusername's bookmarks</source>
  <category domain="http://www.delicious.com/myusername/">iPhone</category>
  <category domain="http://www.delicious.com/myusername/">gesture</category>
  <category domain="http://www.delicious.com/myusername/">objc</category>
  <category domain="http://www.delicious.com/myusername/">gesture-recognization</category>
</item>
```

here is my jQuery code, i take rss input from textarea with id "rss" and trying to print the link in firebug console.

`feed = $('#rss').val();`

$(feed).find('item').each(function(){
console.log($(this).children().eq(3).text());

});

For some reason the complete xml is not rendered correctly, here is the pastebin link of delicious feed http://pastebin.com/KbDNyL0P

**Update:**
It seems that I was using some wrong version/distro of jQuery, I copied jQuery from a plugin directory that causes the issue. Lesson learnt: always download from jQuery/GoogleCode site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using json

http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/myusername?count=15

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   data: 'count=15',
   jsonp: 'callback',
   url: 'http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/myusername?callback=?',
   success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(i,item){
         console.log(item.u);
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: thnx will try and update. Delicious only provide 100 bookmarks at the max with JSON where as RSS can fetch all the links at once. I'm looking for rss solution here.